# Lag function for dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using LAG SQL function to get the difference of 2 consecutive dates in the records. THe issue is, the result it is returning is in DATE -TIME format whereas I want it either to be in Days, or hours. Attached is Output it outcome and the expected result.

Code:

```
select 
   *, 
   (action_date - lag(action_date) over (partition by voucher_no order by action_date)) as diff 
from cte3
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sugadha. If I understand your question, you should probably be using `DATEDIFF` rather than `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `time` for the last column -- although it does give you seconds as well:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date), Date ) AS diff_day,
       CONVERT(TIME, Date - LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date)) as time
FROM t;
```

It is simple enough to convert this to just HH:MM format if you prefer:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date), Date ) AS diff_day,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CONVERT(TIME, Date - LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date))) as time_hhmm
FROM t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=759b41a38858e4b38e67581fb199a670) is a db<>fiddle.

I prefer this method because it is easier to format the time.  In particular, the fiddle includes an example where the time is 00:01 and it is formatted as `00:01` rather than `0:1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEDIFF()` function such as

```
SELECT 
  DATEDIFF(day, LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date), Date ) AS diff_day,
  CONCAT(
         DATEDIFF(minute, LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date), Date )/60,
         ':',
         DATEDIFF(minute, LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date), Date )%60
  ) AS diff_hour_minute, *            
  FROM t
```

in order to get the desired difference values.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fecd57b5eefc816af82acbe3679476d2)</kbd>